# Google Code Prettify - How to fix SQL escape character

Tags: javascript, regex, prettify, google-code-prettify

I'm trying to fix the following issue, as it's being very annoying on my site.
https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=341&thanks=341&ts=1398085413

and refers to the following file of the prettify code:
https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-sql.js?r=179

The issue is that

1. When in SQL creating a string that ends with a "\", the highlighter thinks it is escaped, while this is not T-SQL syntax.
2. To reproduce, use this code as source code: (with Google Code Prettify installed)

   ```
   <pre class="prettyprint lang-sql">
    SELECT @BUPath = 'c:\backups\' + @DBName + '-B4 CHANGE.bak'
    SELECT @BUName = @DBName + '-B4 CHANGE'
   </pre>
   ```

I would expect the code to understand that the slash before the quote in the part 'c:\backups\' is not an escaping character...

I am expecting that this line would need to be changed, but I am not sure how:

```
[PR['PR_STRING'],      /^(?:"(?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^\'\\]|\\.)*')/, null,
      '"\'']
```

fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/JH5uj/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the PR_STRING definition at https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-sql.js must have been copied from some other language where backslash is an escape character.

```
/^(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')/
```

does it as far as I can tell, but being a mere database guy I could be missing something.

(Sorry to be late to the party with this, but I just hit the same issue and found this thread.)

Comment: Are double quotes used for string literals in SQL Server? In Oracle "xyz" would be an identifier, not a string. If they're not, it's just /^'[^']*'/

Comment: I checked and you can lose the double-quotes too. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx

Comment: @WilliamRobertson For SQL Server (T-SQL). 1) string literals are between single-quotes only. 2) Backslash for T-SQL is not an escape character.

Comment: In ANSI-SQL backslash in the escape character, except to escape single and double quotes. So the `lang-sql` implements this as such, AFAICT it wasn't blindly copied.

Comment: @TT. - that's interesting. There is certainly no escape character in Oracle SQL (my background) and apparently not in MS SQL either according to the OP. I found [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0015.htm) for Informix, which also mentions ANSI in passing - but then goes on to say ANSI SQL does *not* allow escaping of quotes with backslash. I could only find [this SQL-1992 document](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), which doesn't mention it.

Comment: @TT. just noticed you're saying the same thing. So `lang-sql` is wrong to allow a backslash to escape a quote, right?

Comment: (Edited=) Yes. ANSI-SQL does not allow escaping of single quote and double quote with a backslash.

Comment: Tbh, I got that from this [link at IBM.com](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0015.htm). I don't have an official link to an ANSI SQL standard.